# Tensorflow 2.0 Keras won't save best model even with validation data, still gives me: Can save best model only with val_acc available, skipping

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I provide both training and validation data as Dataset iterators during training by `fit` function. I want to save best model by validation dataset accuracy. However, during training at each epoch, I get warning like `Can save best model only with val_acc, skipping.`

I compiled the model with `metrics = ['accuracy']`, declared `monitor='val_acc'` in callback, and provided validation data as Dataset iterator like `validation_data=my_val_dataset` in `fit`. What else am I missing here?

I would really appreciate any help.

My Jupyter notebook is in [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/shinchan75034/testrep/blob/master/tf20_dist_train.ipynb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `val_acc` exists in the logs.

Get the history from a short training:

```
histCallback = model.fit(smallBatch_X, smallBatch_Y, epochs = 1)
```

Check what is in it:

```
for key in histCallback.history:
    print(key)
```

Maybe you will find `val_accuracy` instead. Or maybe you have multiple outputs and will find `val_output_2_acc` or something in a similar style.

Comment: Yes I found `val_accuracy` as well as `accuracy`. In `histCallback.history` I see array of these values per each epoch. Then in `./training_checkpoints/ckpt_1/` I see one `saved_model`. I have no idea if that's the best model or the model from the last epoch. What does this mean? My revised output per your suggestion is in https://github.com/shinchan75034/testrep/blob/master/tf20_dist_train.ipynb

Comment: @RickBlaine This means that you need `monitor='val_accuracy'`. The value `val_acc` doesn't exist.

Comment: great! Thank you @DanielMöller for the trick to look up proper names for these output arrays. Now I got it to work. I see output like this which shows at this epoch, model assets are saved because validation accuracy is best : `Train for 5 steps, validate for 5 steps
Epoch 1/10
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.4088 - accuracy: 0.8750INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: ./training_checkpoints/ckpt_1/assets`

Comment: Ok :) -- You can disable the message, if you like, with `verbose=0`. -- If you consider that this answers your question, please mark it as answered.