# Warning : Tensorflow: can save best model only with val_accuracy available, skipping

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am building a CNN model for image classification using keras. I am unable to save the best model using ModelCheckPoint as it throws this warning:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val_accuracy
> available, skipping.

I have researched on stackoverflow for all the related questions, but nothing has worked so far. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69072372/why-am-i-not-able-to-perform-validation-test-at-every-epoch-end) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505749/tensorflowcan-save-best-model-only-with-val-acc-available-skipping)  [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776622/keras-callbacks-keep-skip-saving-checkpoints-claiming-val-acc-is-missing)  [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58071917/tensorflow-2-0-keras-wont-save-best-model-even-with-validation-data-still-give)  and more

Here's my code:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy', Precision(), Recall()],optimizer='adam')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255.,
                                rotation_range   =40,
                                width_shift_range=0.2,
                                height_shift_range=0.2,
                                shear_range=0.2,
                                zoom_range =0.2,
                                horizontal_flip=True,
                                fill_mode ='nearest')
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255.)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(r"./datasetcrop512/train", target_size=(512,512), batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical')
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(r"./datasetcrop512/test", target_size=(512,512), batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical')
```

After augmentation, model checkpoint

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
filepath = 'weights_best_model3_6.hdf5'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath,monitor = 'val_accuracy',verbose = 1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
```

fit the model

```
history = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch = stepsPerEpoch,
       epochs = 15, validation_data=test_generator, validation_steps = stepsPerEpoch,
       callbacks = [ PlotLossesKeras(),checkpoint])
```

After running, validation accuracy is calculated for 1st epoch, but from 2nd epoch it starts giving the aforementioned warning and doesn't save the best model.

Comment: I remember seeing a similar issue before, it was due to using `validation_steps` when the validation data wasn't of type `tf.data.Dataset`, can you try removing `validation_steps` parameter and try again?.

Comment: @aim97 Hey this actually worked :D I'll test 2-3 times more and let you know if it works always.

Comment: @aim97 please post the solution as an answer, so that OP can accept and be useful for others in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems similar to another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401692/cnn-validation-dataset-doesnt-work-while-model-fit/69402370#69402370) that i saw before, the use of `validation_steps` is only allowed under some conditions as stated in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

> **validation_steps** : Only relevant if validation_data is provided and is a `tf.data` dataset. ...

The data you provided is not from the required type to make it work, validating this way requires the given dataset to be either very large or to use `repeat` method to repeat itself to accommodate the number of validation batches you want, i believe that's why validation only worked at the first time then stopped for the rest.

Check also this better explanation of the parameters [steps_per_epoch and validation_steps](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29719/how-to-set-batch-size-steps-per-epoch-and-validation-steps) and when to use them.